# SVN 1.8 how to stop re-integration when you merge a branch back to a trunk

Tags: svn, merge

Frequently, we do some work on a branch, then need to put those fixes into the trunk, then carry on modifying the branch.  At some point way down the line we may want to permanently re-integrate the branch.

with 1.7 this was easy, just say "svn merge path_to_branch" whist in the trunk directory, and not include the "--reintegrate" switch.

with 1.8, this does not seem possible, as it will automatically do the re-integration.  We cant find a --dont-reintegrate switch.

The only work around we can see is to edit both the branch and the trunk using cut and paste of the same changes, which we presume is very bad due to losing the merge/revision info.

There is a [section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice) on how to recover from reintegration, aka "Keeping a Reintegrated Branch Alive", but for us this is rocket science, and way beyond what we can use safely - we want to avoid this by not reintegrating in the first place.

Another manual hack which we might work but we are too scared to try it, is to do the merge, which modifies the root directory with a new property change ("svn:merginfo"), then "revert" this dir property change (but not the file changes) before committing.  However, we don't really know if this will break anything.  We assume it might.

Anyone else have a better solution?  It seems that 1.8 has introduced a whole new level of the "keep alive dance".

## UPDATE:

Unfortunately, this subject is now moot - it is now not possible with SVN to merge a release branch back to trunk.  When we try to run this:

```
cd trunkdir
svn merge https:bla.com/svn/co/proj/braches/1.1.1
```

we get

svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 1514 through 1634 were previously merged from https:bla.com/svn/co/proj/trunk to the reintegrate source, but this is not the case: proj/branches/1.9.11 Missing ranges: /proj/trunk:1514,1516-1519,1555-1558,1563,1577,1586,1596-1597,1599

this is saying that in order to push our features/fixes back from the branch to the trunk, we have to merge the trunk with the branch first.  The branch is a certified release branch - we cant possibly put trunk code in it!  So now we are really stuck.  We could hand edit every change manually back tot he trunk, but this is going to be a nightmare to manage.  Presumably hand editing is going to make re-integrating the two in the future harder.  I cant believe SVN doesn't support "release" branches, which fixes to the release which occasionally need to go back to trunk.

The very strange thing is we did this command before, didnt get this error (so merged the branch back to the trunk without having to merge trunk to branch), and we reverted the changes (and didnt commit).  It appears we have done something between now and then which has broken our ability to merge.  If we do:

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo --depth=infinity
```

in the root of trunk, we get nothing.  If we do it in the branch, we get one file which we cherry picked from trunk to branch some time ago (a bug fix).

Comment: "At some point way down the line we may want to permanently re-integrate the branch." please elaborate: for mee it seems as delirium

Comment: The documentation says that you cannot reintegrate a branch twice (without getting conficts), that once you have reintegrated, you should create a new branch, or go through the "keep branch alive dance".  We need to keep the branch alive, and copy changes from branch to trunk without reintegrating.  1.8 merge now reintegrates by default, with no way to "opt out" of applying the "--reintegration" flag.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use 1.7 "keep-alive" recipes for 1.8: this area was greatly changed 1.8 in direction **to have simplicity**
2. Every merge in 1.8 is reintegration merge without the dance "merge before modified trunk to branch in order to have clean branch-only changes", thus - "re-integrate the branch" disappear as task for 1.8 - you have live branch after any amount of merges of *this* branch to it's parent, any new merge merges only new changes from branch to parent
3. Can't see any reason *in real life* for having `--dont-reintegrate` option, because reintegration doesn't broke anything
4. Describe your **business-task** in *plain English*, if my reconstruction of your troubles was wrong

Comment: Hi, if you are saying that in 1.8 you can reintegrate multiple times without issues, then this is great news.  What I have read till now, even refering to 1.8, says you should never reintegrate a branch twice, as it will lead to conflicts, but if this is not the case we are good.

Comment: if the 1.7 keep alive recipe doesn't work for 1.8, does anyone have an equivalent for 1.8?

Comment: @JohnLittle - recipe is easy "merge branch when it's needed, commit to branch while it's needed"

Comment: Sadly, this recipe does not work for a release branch - it seems you can't merge a branch with the trunk without first merging the trunk to the branch (see update above), which we cant do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ?:

1. Copy/branch your "release" branch, creating "merge_branch" branch.
2. Merge "trunk" into the "merge_branch".
3. Merge "merge_branch" into "trunk".

Apologies if this was the first thing you tried.

Comment: this is a comment to the question (not an answer). (eventually because of low rep.)

Comment: This is an interesting work around, which looks like it should work.  When we come to re-integrate in the future, we will have to re-integrate the merge-branch, not the release_branch.